# Powershell reading multiple variables from text file

Tags: file, powershell, loops, variables, foreach

I'm quite new to PS, so please don't kill me if the resolution is so easy :)
I've tried to find a solution here and in google, but no luck.

This is part of code which don't work as I want

```
$Contents = Get-Content "Path\test.txt"

foreach($Line in $Contents) {
  $Line = $Line.split(":")[1]
  $s = $line -split ':'
  $RegPath = $s[0]
  $Value_Name = $s[1]
  $Type = $s[2]
  $Value = $s[3]
  Write-host $RegPath $Value_Name $Type $Value
  }
```

The output from `Write-Host` is ok, but the main problem is when I want to use those variables after end of `foreach` loop. If I call any variable after `foreach`, for example `Write-Host $Value_Name` it is just empty.

I need to use those variables `$RegPath, $Value_Name, $Type, $Value`
in later code of script. I can't figure how to do it. I would appreciate any help/idea how to do it. Thank you in advance

EDIT: Added test.txt

```
Just some text to ignore :Software\Test
Just some text to ignore :Test
Just some text to ignore :String
Just some text to ignore :Value
```

And the output from the first Write-Host in foreach is correct

```
Software/Test
Test
String
Value
```

And when I want to use for example just `$Value_Name`, the output is empty after `foreach`

Comment: Can you post a sample of what is in 'test.txt'?  It looks like you might be using colon-separated values, which means that `Import-Csv -Delimiter ":"` might be an option.

Comment: It would be much easier to follow your code if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50875649/edit) your question to contain a sample line of your file `"Path\test.txt"`

Comment: Edited main post

Comment: IMO the `Just some text to ignore :` is impotant to identify the lines, to not just rely on the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misconception:

- while iterating the ForEach each `$Line` is split and returns a single
  item.   $s[0..3] would only be populated if there were at least three
  colons in the same Line.
- Provided you want to assign the colon separated values of the first 4 lines to these variables, try this

---

```
$Contents = Get-Content "Path\test.txt"

$RegPath    = $Contents[0].split(":")[1]
$Value_Name = $Contents[1].split(":")[1]
$Type       = $Contents[2].split(":")[1]
$Value      = $Contents[3].split(":")[1]

Write-host ("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}" -f $RegPath,$Value_Name,$Type,$Value)
```

Sample output

```
Software\Test|Test|String|Value
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfectly and thanks for a explanation!

Answer (score 2):

### Edit: changing the answer due to misunderstanding of file format. Will leave it here as it might be helpful for someone in the future.

Before the loop use:

```
$outputFromLoop = @()
```

And in the loop use:

```
foreach ($Line in $Contents) {
    # Here goes your code and variables RegPath, Value_Name, Type, Value are assigned

    # Add this:
    $object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "RegPath" –Value $RegPath 
    $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Value_Name" –Value $Value_Name
    $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Type" –Value $Type
    $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Value" –Value $Value
    $outputFromLoop += $object
  }
```

Now you can list all the values:

```
$outputFromLoop
```

Or just access any element by index:

```
$outputFromLoop[0]
```

Properties can be accessed like this:

```
$outputFromLoop[0].RegPath
$outputFromLoop[0].Value_Name
$outputFromLoop[0].Type
$outputFromLoop[0].Value
```

Test the output:

```
Write-Host  $outputFromLoop[0].RegPath $outputFromLoop[0].Value_Name $outputFromLoop[0].Type $outputFromLoop[0].Value
```

#### Short explanation

What you basically do here is to create custom object `$object` for each `$Line` and add this to `$outputFromLoop` array. Once you finish `ForEach` loop you can access any element and its property based on the examples below the code.

Comment: Almost perfect. But the most important thing `$outputFromLoop[0].RegPath
$outputFromLoop[0].Value_Name
$outputFromLoop[0].Type
$outputFromLoop[0].Value` is empty. 
Tried to change index but still without luck. The previous outputs work correctly, but the "view" of it is unusable for me

Comment: I added `Write-Host` to my answer, can you check? Tested on my side.

Comment: `Write-Host` just returned me only `Software\Test  `

Comment: Check LotPings answer, that explains a lot. Does your file contains only these 4 lines or more? I'll change my script to cover it.

Comment: Checked and it works. Thanks! 
BTW. Right now it has only 4 lines but I will modify it if I will need more. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you're better of changing the inputfile from a text file with 4 values on separate lines to a proper .CSV file where you can store multiple reg properties under a heading of `"RegPath","Value_Name","Type","Value"`. Easy to maintain and easy to load with `Import-Csv`

Comment: Excellent technique for keeping associated data together! In PoS 3.0 and later, you can use `$object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName _name_ -NotePropertyValue _value_` to make it a little more tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You could create hashtables and "save" them in an array

```
$Contents = Get-Content "Path\test.txt"
$list = @()

foreach($Line in $Contents) {
  $Line = $Line.split(":")[1]
  $s = $line -split ':'
  $RegPath = $s[0]
  $Value_Name = $s[1]
  $Type = $s[2]
  $Value = $s[3]
  Write-host $RegPath $Value_Name $Type $Value

  $list += @{Regpath=$Regpath;Name=$Value_Name;Type=$Type;Value=$Value}
}
```

There are other possibilities like a two dimensional array for example.

Answer (score 0):

after the loop you'll have just the last values, because your variables are receveing and override the previous values.
You need to do all things insde the loop. Each interation are one set of values.

```
$Contents = Get-Content "Path\test.txt"

foreach($Line in $Contents) {
  $Line = $Line.split(":")[1]
  $s = $line -split ':'
  $RegPath = $s[0]
  $Value_Name = $s[1]
  $Type = $s[2]
  $Value = $s[3]
  Write-host $RegPath $Value_Name $Type $Value

  # do here the operations
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't make me happy, because this is just a small part of bigger script and I need to use those 4 variables in later use. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to do it. The foreach loop is just to put strings in variables for later use