# Powershell Loop through a text file and split by colon

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I have a text file with content similar to below:

```
----------------------------------------
Title: Textbook
Client: ABC
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Title: Comic book
Client: DEF
----------------------------------------
```

I want to split each line by colon and store left side in a variable called "Title" and the right side in another variable and so on...so that when I print the output, I get something similar to the following:

```
$Title has been sold to $Client
```

Here is my script so far. I've tried some examples in [Powershell reading multiple variables from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875649/powershell-reading-multiple-variables-from-text-file) but it's been no luck and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my current script.

```
$data = Get-Content "C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.log" | Where { $_ -notmatch '^-.*' -and $_ -notmatch '^\s*$' } 

$outputFromLoop = @() 
$data | foreach-object {

    $key, $value = ($_ -split ':',2).trim()
    $outputFromLoop[$key] = $value

}
$outputFromLoop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using a `switch` statement:

```
$hash = [ordered]@{}
switch -regex -file test.log {
  '^-+' { if ($hash.Count -ne 0) { 
            "{0} has been sold to {1}" -f $hash.Title,$hash.Client
          }
          $hash = [ordered]@{} 
  }
  '^([^:]+):(.+)' { $key,$value = $matches[1].Trim(),$matches[2].Trim()
                    $hash.Add($key,$value) 
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `-regex` switch uses regex matching against each line of the file. `^-+` matches any line that begins with one or more `-`. `^([^:]+):(.+)` matches any line that begins with non-colon characters, followed by a colon, followed by characters. The first group of parentheses comprises capture group 1 (`$matches[1]`). The second group of parentheses comprises capture group 2 (`$matches[2]`).

`$matches` will be populated on lines that contain `:` and don't begin with `-`. Each time a line that begins with `-` is reached, the hash table (`$hash`) that contains `Client` and `Title` will have its values retrieved and output in a string with the requested format. Then the hash table is reinitialized.

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine. One more thing I'm just wondering if you can help is the possibility of continuously reading the file? I know it can be done with Get-Content -wait but i'm not so sure with the use of switch -file...

Comment: I'm trying this out: switch -regex (Get-Content test.log -Wait)...by the way

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as I add a new block of text in...the script keeps running without returning anything

Comment: I think I found the solution: `Get-Content test.log -Wait | 
ForEach-Object {
switch -regex ($_)`

Answer (score 2):

I would read the file in as one large multi-line string, split it on the `------` lines to get individual records, do a little format updating (convert colons to equals signs and kill some whitespace), then use `ConvertFrom-StringData` to make objects you can work with.

```
$RawText = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt -raw
$Sales = $RawText -split '(?:^|[\r\n])-+(?:[\r\n]|$)' -replace '(Title|Client):\s*','$1='|Where{$_}|ForEach-Object{New-Object PSObject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData $_)}
$Sales | ForEach-Object {
    "{0} was sold to {1}" -f $_.Title, $_.Client
}
```

That results in:

```
Textbook was sold to ABC
Comic book was sold to DEF
```

It also leaves you with an array of objects that you could use to track sales per client, or see who all has purchased what items. (such as `$Sales | Group Client`).

Comment: Thank you. I tried although it worked, I couldn't understand the logic :(

Answer (score 1):

You can import the file as csv and use : as the delimiter

```
$content = Import-Csv C:\temp\file.txt -Delimiter : -Header Field1, Field2 | ? { $_.Field1 -notmatch "-+" }

$i = 0
while ($i -lt $csv.Count) {

  $title = $csv[$i++].Field2
  $client = $csv[$i++].Field2
  Write-output "$title sold to $client"
}

#Prints to console:
Textbook sold to ABC
Comic book sold to DEF
```

Or you can read in the file and get only the matching Titles and Clients.. then use the same index for each to get the desired output.

```
$content = Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt

$Titles = $content -match "Title: " | % { $_ -replace "Title: ", "" }
$Clients = $content -match "Client: " | % { $_ -replace "Client: ", ""}

if ($Titles.Length -ne $Clients.Length) {
    Write-Output "Not the same"
}

$outputFromLoop = @{}
for($i = 0; $i -lt $titles.Length; $i++) {
    Write-Output "$($Titles[$i]) sold to $($Clients[$i])"
    $outputFromLoop[$Titles[$i]] = $Clients[$i]
}

# Prints the same
Textbook sold to ABC
Comic book sold to DEF

$outputFromLoop:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Textbook                       ABC                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Comic book                     DEF
```

of course, this relies **heavily** on the fact that your text file would contain both Title and Client one after another.

Comment: it didn't work for me even though I tried $outputFromLoop....Is there a way that I can loop through all of those variables as there are other fields in my text file as well instead of just $Titles and $Clients? For example textbook sold to ABC at the price of $price_point...

Comment: @HoDiep I fixed the variable... for some reason I got $output instead of $OutputFromLoop within the loop.try again

Answer (score 0):

here's yet another way to  do it. [*grin*] this one uses named capture groups and the `(?ms)` multiline & single line options of the dotnet regex engine to parse the blocks of text.

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file as one multiline string
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Raw
$InStuff = @'
----------------------------------------
Title: Textbook
Client: ABC
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Title: Comic book
Client: DEF
----------------------------------------
'@
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file as one multiline string

# split by the lines of hyphens
$SplitInStuff = ($InStuff -split '-{1,}').
    # trim away the unwanted whitespace & non-printing chars
    Trim().
    # remove all the blank lines
    Where({$_})

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $SplitInStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match '(?ms)Title: (?<Title>.+)$.*Client: (?<Client>.+)'

    # send the object out to the $Results collection
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Title = $Matches.Title
        Client = $Matches.Client
        }

    Write-Host ('{0} has been sold to {1}.' -f $Matches.Title, $Matches.Client)
    Write-Host ('=' * 10)
    }

# if you want only the screen display, then you can remove the "$Results = " and the next line
#    the would allow you to use the extracted info - perhaps save it to a CSV file
$Results
```

output ...

```
Textbook has been sold to ABC.
==========
Comic book has been sold to DEF.
==========

Title       Client
-----       ------
Textbook... ABC   
Comic bo... DEF
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to dynamically assign the capture group name based on the previous capture group? Something like (this doesn't work) `'(?ms)(Title|Client):\s*(?<\1>\S.*)'` ...I was just thinking in case there is inconsistencies with order, that wouldn't care much.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - i cannot think of any way to cover that idea in one step. [*blush*] however, one could use two match steps ... one for each item.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thank you. I tested your solution but I got multiple repeated lines instead of one per each...My text file got 4 blocks of texts, 2 blocks for same client...and it repeated the same client 6 times...

Comment: if your sample data is not a realistic match for your actual data ... how do you expect anyone to provide code that works with the -actual_ data? [*grin*] **_i recommend you provide realistic sample data to test the code with._**